# using php sdk 2.0.4 for Quickbooks online API v3 Cannot parse Payment that has LineEx

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am using the php sdk 2.0.4 for Quickbooks online API v3 to do Payment related processing.
I use the sdk in the following way:

```
$result = $dataService->FindById(
  new IPPPayment( array( 'Id' => 12345 ), true) 
);
```

The id of the payment I want to get is 12345.  Using the API explorer from the Intuit Partnership Platform (IPP) website, I am able to get back a non-null result:

```
<IntuitResponse>
  <Payment domain="QBO" sparse="false">
    <Id>12345</Id>
    ...
    <TxnDate>2013-10-15</TxnDate>
    <Line>
      <Amount>660.00</Amount>
      <LinkedTxn>
        <TxnId>216</TxnId>
        <TxnType>Invoice</TxnType>
      </LinkedTxn>
      <LineEx>
        <NameValue>
          <Name>txnId</Name>
          <Value>216</Value>
        </NameValue>
        <NameValue>
          <Name>txnOpenBalance</Name>
          <Value>790.00</Value>
        </NameValue>
        <NameValue>
          <Name>txnReferenceNumber</Name>
          <Value>7030</Value>
        </NameValue>
      </LineEx>
    </Line>
    <CustomerRef name="XXXXXXXXX">66</CustomerRef>
    <DepositToAccountRef>51</DepositToAccountRef>
    <TotalAmt>660.00</TotalAmt>
    <UnappliedAmt>0</UnappliedAmt>
    <ProcessPayment>false</ProcessPayment>
  </Payment>
</IntuitResponse>
```

Using the php sdk, I get a null value instead.  With some troubleshooting, I found that an exception was thrown when the xml msg was being deserialized into php object around `v3-php-sdk-2.0.4/Dependencies/XSD2PHP/src/com/mikebevz/xsd2php/Bind.php` line 112.

The exception message was: 'Property NameValue does not exist.  Class IPPIntuitAnyType'.  The parsing at that point appears to be processing the `<LineEx>` element of the xml, but fails to parse it.  Could this be a missing data class representing LineEx in the php sdk?  or how to best fix this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yesterday, I ran into the same problem with this library in a system which has been using the API without issue since March. I assume that Intuit changed something about the XML structure or something, but nobody has updated the "v3-php-sdk" code to match. This post on their community forum from June describes a similar case:

- https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com/questions/939250-why-is-my-php-sdk-unable-to-parse-qbo-s-purchase-responses

I was able to apply the suggested workaround by modifying lines 109-113 of **Bind.php** to be the following:

```
try {
    $propertyDocs = $refl->getProperty($name)->getDocComment();
} catch (\ReflectionException $e) {
    if ($name == "NameValue") continue; // QB APIv3 bug!
    else throw new \RuntimeException($e->getMessage().". Class ".get_class($model));
}
```

It's ugly, but it works, and I couldn't find any other way around it. Note that only the code inside the `catch { }` block is actually modified.

Comment: You are a lifesaver @jeff Its shocking how many bugs the "v3-php-sdk" still has for what I would assume are very common tasks for any application integrating with Quickbooks. You definitely saved me a bunch of time with this one.

Comment: Thanks, I ran into the same issue